# Retrieving part of a string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, substring

I am parsing an html page using the `Html Agility Pack`. I am successful in getting the following text in a string:

```
 
WOCN11 CWTO 170951

Special weather statement

Updated by Environment Canada

At 5:51 AM EDT Friday 17 June 2011.



Special weather statement issued for..

Sarnia - Lambton

London - Middlesex

Oxford - Brant

Waterloo - Wellington.

---------------------------------------------------------------------

Dense fog patches with near zero visibility have been reported in

The above areas. Extra caution is urged for travellers in these 

areas.



Fog is expected to lift shortly after sunrise this morning.



END/OSPC

ACCN10 CWTO 170735

Forecast of thunderstorm potential for the province of Ontario

Issued by Environment Canada at 3:35 AM EDT Friday 17 June 2011.

The next statement will be issued at 4.30 PM today.

---------------------------------------------------------------------

Forecast of thunderstorm potential.



Today..Isolated non severe thunderstorms over eastern

And Northeastern Ontario.



Tonight..Isolated non severe thunderstorms over eastern and 

Northeastern Ontario this evening.



Saturday..Isolated non severe thunderstorms over extreme

Southwestern Ontario mainly late in the afternoon and evening.



---------------------------------------------------------------------

A thunderstorm is defined as severe if it produces one or more of the 

following:



 - wind gusts of 90 km/h or greater.

 - hail of 2 centimetres in diameter or greater.

 - rainfall amounts of 50 millimetres or greater in one hour or less.

 - a tornado.



Note: this forecast is issued twice daily from May 1 to September 30.



END/OSPC
```

And I want to extract only the following part:

```
Forecast of thunderstorm potential.



Today..Isolated non severe thunderstorms over eastern

And Northeastern Ontario.



Tonight..Isolated non severe thunderstorms over eastern and 

Northeastern Ontario this evening.



Saturday..Isolated non severe thunderstorms over extreme

Southwestern Ontario mainly late in the afternoon and evening.
```

I am using Csharp on .Net 3.5. Any help appreciated.

**Question Updated**

Comment: So you want the section of text between the 2nd and 3rd lines of hyphens.  Is it guaranteed that you will ALWAYS want that specific section?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do that automatically. Extracting the string is easy, but figuring out which string to extract would be a problem. Environment Canada isn't that predictable in their wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could do it (although not 100% ideal), is like this:

```
string[] textSplit = theWholeTextString.Split(new string[] { "---------------------------------------------------------------------" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string myText = textSplit[2];
```

Assuming of course, that the text you want is always in the 3rd section, and each section is always separated by the '------' line

Comment: I had the same suggestion.  I think you need to modify your code, though, as the overload for string.Split can take an array of chars or an array of strings.  If you don't specify the array type, it assumes chars.  It will throw an exception the way you have it in double quotes.

Comment: what if there are no `-------------------` and only the text to differentiate between the string and the substring?

Comment: I think you may have to then search for keywords in the text that you're only likely to find in the section you're looking for.  Like 'Today' or 'Tomorrow' or 'Monday'.  Other than that, I'm not sure.  The text is not very structured.  Can you get any more information about it from the source, or from another source?

Answer (score 0):

For us to be able to help you, you would need to tell us how we can define what text to keep. Is it a line of '---' + 'Forecast' up to the last '---' line or is it something else, etc... A regExp will do the job, but the exact syntax I can't tell without more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that only the stuff between the `-------------` lines is what you want, try this regular expression: `-{40,}([\s\S](?=-{40,}))-{40,}`.

```
Regex.Match(report, @"-{40,}([\s\S](?=-{40,}))-{40,}").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only thing delimiting your text is the --------------------------------------------------------------------- characters.

How about using string.Split().  Here is an example:

```
string[] textArray = wholeText.Split(new string[] {"---------------------------------------------------------------------"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string text = textArray[2];
```